# Mobile scroll animation Lag - jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm trying to replicate a scroll Animation I found from the talanted Web Designer Nathan Riley (https://nrly.co/).

I've accomplished that pretty easy with some small code changing an attribute in the svg filter code from html. The problem though is, that when viewing the page on mobile, that animation is realy slow and lagging.

The code I wrote:

html filter:

```
<svg>
    <defs>
        <filter id="liquify">
            <feturbulence basefrequency="0" numoctaves="3" result="warp" type="fractalNoise"></feturbulence>
            <fedisplacementmap in="SourceGraphic" in2="warp" scale="100" xchannelselector="R" ychannelselector="B"></fedisplacementmap>
        </filter>
    </defs>
</svg>
```

applying the filter in css:

```
.liquify {
filter: url(#liquify);}
```

jQuery code to animate with scrollTop:

```
function liqScroll() {
var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
$("#liquify > feTurbulence").attr({
    'baseFrequency' : +scrollTop / 100000,
});};
```

Do you guys know how to fix/workaround the lag?

sitenote: on firefox I get the following message in the console, which might have something to do with it:

> This site appears to use a scroll-linked positioning effect. This may not work well with asynchronous panning; see https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Mozilla/Performance/ScrollLinkedEffects for further details and to join the discussion on related tools and features!

Comment: You can see this Firefox warning each time you use script to monitor scroll and position elements depending on it. Mobile devices usually do not use direct monitoring of `scroll` event, but instead do all calculations **after** the event occurs - that is why you see kind of lagging.

Comment: so the nrly.co porfolio works perfectly fine on mobile. what is his trick/how could I fix that?

Comment: actually, I just found out that the firefox warning has nothing to do with it. it appears from another function that I use to fade out elements on scroll.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out by now, the reason causing the lags for me, was a missing viewport meta tag in html. That caused to have a default zoom level, which made the animation update less frequently, causing the lags.

Also using the js plugin [ScrollMagic](http://scrollmagic.io) works great for that purpose instead of writing the code yourselfe.